# Как сделать range slider с ненормированым шагом?

Tags: javascript, rangeslider

На этой странице есть слайдер расчета стоимости биткоина. https://www.coinmama.com/ru

Он сделан с ненормированым шагом. Подскажите, такой шаг можно высчитать по какой то математической формуле?
Пока в голову приходит только следующее. Определить, на каком отрезке находится пимпочка и относительно значений этого отрезка высчитывать диапазон.

Comment: а взять сам слайдер и использовать? http://egorkhmelev.github.io/jslider/

Comment: Оу! Действительно! Спасибо! Не доглядел.